# Post information to Asp.net page method?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http, iis, jquery

*This is a "How it is  done behind the scenes" question :*

Im posting data from jQuery ajax to an asp.net page **method**. ( the method name is `Show1`)

Fiddler shows  :

```
POST http://localhost:54517/WebSite8/Default.aspx/Show1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:54517
 ...

{aaa:"value"}
```

*Is just like posting to asmx.*

the `iis` gets a request to `/Show1`  **but** he doesn't have a page like this.

so *how* does he knows that he should run `Default.aspx` *and* search a `Show1` method inside it ?

Also  , If this method is declared as :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Show1(string aaa)
    {}
```

Is it legitimic question to ask for its *WSDL alike information* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default.aspx/Show1 is the natural URL structure for static web methods in a page, so the framework handles the request and routes it correctly.

As far as WSDL, I'm not sure since it's not a pure web service how the WSDL comes into play.